# Can't add scrollbar when using flex-grow

Tags: flexbox, scrollbar, overflow

I want .lines-wrapper to have a scroll when the .line-row takes up more than 270 px. I loop out multiple .line-row and they need to adjust to the height that is available, hence using flex-grow. I want to have a min-height set to 270px and there line-row should be able to overflow and a scroll should be added. I can't get it to work. Any solutions for this case?

I have tested other solutions for this without any success

```css
.lineup-area-container {
  max-width: 1366px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.lines-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 270px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    margin: 0 50px;
  }
}

.line-row {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-height: 122px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.jersey-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 122px;
}
```

Comment: Knowing what the CSS applies to is a rather important detail, wouldn't you agree?